# multiplying both sides by $\cos(m\pi x)$ and integrating from $0$ t0 $1$ with respect to $x$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have come across the following in my textbook and I am a little confused by it

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left( Y''_n - n^2 \pi ^2 Y_n(y) \right ) \cos (n\pi x) = \cosh(\pi y) \cos(\pi x)$$
where
$$q_0 = 0$$$$ q_1 = \cosh(\pi y )$$$$q_n = 0, n\geq 2 $$

This part here is where I am a little confused, it says to multiply both sides of the above equation by $\cos(m\pi x)$ a integrate from $0$ to $1$ with respect to $x$ which gives the following,

$$m = 0 \rightarrow Y_0'' = 0 $$
$$m = 1 \rightarrow Y_1'' - \pi ^2 Y_1 = \cosh (\pi y)$$
$$m\geq 2 \rightarrow Y_m'' - m^2 \pi ^2 Y_m = 0 $$

I am not understanding multiplying both sides by $\cos(m\pi x)$ and intergrating from $0$ t0 $1$ with respect to $x$

for instance,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left( Y''_n - n^2 \pi ^2 Y_n(y) \right ) \int_0^1\cos (m\pi x) \cos(n\pi x)  \\ = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left( Y''_n - n^2 \pi ^2 Y_n(y) \right ) \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\cos (2m\pi x) + 1dx \\ = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left( Y''_n - n^2 \pi ^2 Y_n(y) \right ) \frac{1}{2}\left[ \frac{sin(n\pi m x)}{2m \pi} + x \Bigg|^1_0\right ] $$

Comment: @Bernard thanks for your edit, would you be able to help me with my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your question, there's an error at the second line. You should have
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left( Y''_n - n^2 \pi ^2 Y_n(y) \right ) \int_0^1\cos (m\pi x) \cos(n\pi x) \,\mathrm d x  \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left( Y''_n - n^2 \pi ^2 Y_n(y) \right ) \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \bigl(\cos(m+n)\pi x) + \cos(m-n)\bigr)\,\mathrm d x \tag{1}\\ &= 
\left( Y''_m - m^2 \pi ^2 Y_m(y) \right ) \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \bigl(\cos(2m \pi x) + 1\bigr)\,\mathrm d x \tag{2}\\ 
&=\left( Y''_m - m^2 \pi ^2 Y_m(y) \right )\frac{1}{2}\left[ \frac{\sin(2m\pi x)}{2m \pi} + x \right ]^1_0 =\frac{1}{2}\left( Y''_m - m^2 \pi ^2 Y_m(y) \right )
\end{align}

Equality $(2)$ results from the integrals in $(1)$ being $0\,$ if $\,n\ne m$.

Comment: thanks for your submission, do I need to integrating the RHS or can I just use the facts I know that $q_0 = 0, q_ 1 = cosh(\pi y ), q_2 = 0?$

Comment: What  exactly is denoted by $q_i$, in this context?